# non decreasing CDF

Tags: probability, examples-counterexamples

Can someone, with enough goodwill, give me an example of a non-decreasing ( "croissant" in french) but not increasing ( "strictement croissant" in french) cumulative distribution function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to achieve that is to give the smallest possible value in the domain, a probability of one, and all the other values a probability of zero. Then the cdf is one everywhere.

Comment: euh.. i didn't really understand. All CDF are not always bijective so i want an example of a law with this kind of CD. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm not french, but wouldn't "strictement croissant" translate to strictly increasing? In that case we could take for example the CDF of a poisson random variable (or some other discrete variable). It will be constant on any interval on the form $[n,n+1)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen yes you are right abotut "strictement croissant".

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen but i don't see why the cdf of poisson random variable is not bijective (and therefore not strictly increasing). Thanks for your answer

Comment: Consider poisson(1) and let $F$ be the CDF. For $x < 0$  we have $F(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ we have $F(x) = e^{-1}$, but there is no $x$ such $F(x)$ is say $e^{-1}/2$. Conclusion it is not bijective (at least not with [0,1] as codomain).

Comment: Thanks i understand way better. I have a question. Is every discret law have a cdf non strictly increasing?

Comment: Yes any reasonable discrete law you will ever encounter would have that property, in fact the CDF will be a step function. I suppose one could construct a counter-example if we consider a random variable, which takes any rational number with positive probability, then the CDF would be strictly increasing, but it would have infinitely many points of discontinuity.